# How to get localstorage items from from redirected url

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to take localstorage items from the second url..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name where the data is stored you can use JS in your console. For example:

`console.log( localStorage.getItem('name') );`
But you can get the data only from the current site where you are visited.